# Using Google Apps to set up emails with a custom domain

Tags: gmail, google-workspace

How do I create email address on my own domain using Google Apps?

Google provided a free service for it, but I can't find where it is or how you go about doing it.

Comment: you need to host your own smtp server 
Also check out this link http://www.geekzone.co.nz/tonyhughes/599  , its pretty old so dont know wheter it would work for you

Comment: http://www.google.com/apps/intl/en/group/index.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Google used to offer a free edition but no longer accepts new sign-ups for it. I have heard that you can sign up for the free trial of the standard edition then downgrade to the free version from within the control panel. I've seen the option myself but not tried it, so this may or may not work.

The standard edition of Google Apps is $5/user/month (or $50/user/year). There is also a version that includes a compliance-friendly archive vault for $10/user/month.